# Using template in c++ - Returning values from method

Tags: c++, templates

I wanna a method that receives a generic type, and a generic type (that's defined in run time). In the example there's if I'm using a string type, It needs to return the first param lenght (in string); If I'm using a int type, needs to return the biggest (int integer).

Have a look:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <atldbcli.h>

#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ADO\msado15.dll" \
 no_namespace rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")

using namespace std;


class Test
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T returnVal(T valueOne, T valueTwo);
};

template<class T>
T Test::returnVal(T valueOne, T valueTwo)
{
    if(typeid(valueOne) == typeid(string))
    {
        string teste = valueOne;
        int testeInt = teste.size();
        ostringstream testeString;
        testeString << testeInt;
        teste = testeString.str();
        return teste;

    }
    else
        return valueOne > valueTwo? valueOne:valueTwo;
}


int main()
{
    string reference = "stringVal";
    Test ref;
    cout << ref.returnVal<string>(reference, "asasas") << endl;
    cout << ref.returnVal<int>(10, 485);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when the main function calls **ref.returnVal(10, 485);** it's show a message error: **'return' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int'**
Does anybody know what's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this is not the proper way to do what you want. You can't use typeid to switch between types and do different operations, because all the different paths still have to be compiled, and inside your if you do return a string while your method returns an int.

google template specialization, that's what you need I guess...

Comment: Generally overloading should be preferred over template specialization for functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>

template <class T> 
int returnVal(T valueOne, T valueTwo);

template <>
int returnVal<std::string>(std::string valueOne, std::string valueTwo)
{
    return (int)valueOne.length();
}

template <>
int returnVal<int>(int valueOne, int valueTwo)
{
    return std::max(valueOne, valueTwo);
}

int main()
{
    int x = returnVal(std::string("Hello"), std::string("World!"));
    int y = returnVal(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you could achieve this with template specialization?

Answer (score 1):

All previous answers clearly identify the problem. As for a better way to do it:

```
class Test
{
public:
    string returnVal(string valueOne, string valueTwo)
    {
        string teste = valueOne;
        int testeInt = teste.size();
        ostringstream testeString;
        testeString << testeInt;
        teste = testeString.str();
        return teste;
    }

    int returnVal(int valueOne, int valueTwo)
    {
        return valueOne > valueTwo? valueOne:valueTwo;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate your template for type `int`, it looks like this:

```
int Test::returnVal(int valueOne, int valueTwo)
{
    if(typeid(valueOne) == typeid(string)) // This will be false
    {
        string teste = valueOne;
        int testeInt = teste.size();
        ostringstream testeString;
        testeString << testeInt;
        teste = testeString.str();
        return teste;

    }
    else
        return valueOne > valueTwo? valueOne:valueTwo;
}
```

The problem is that the then-clause of your `if` returns a string even though the return type of the function is `int`. The fact that the then-clause will never execute because `typeif(valueOne)` can't possible be string doesn't matter because the type checker does not care about that. All he sees is a return statement that returns a string, so that's an error.

To do what you want, you should simply overload your function for strings and remove all the string-specific code from the templated function.